# IE Window launched by JavaScript is accidentally in kiosk mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, kiosk-mode

## Summary

I'm developing an internal web application that contains the following link markup:

```
<a onclick="window.open('/path/to/my/new/page', 'windowname', 'fullscreen,resizable').focus(); return false;" href="/path/to/my/new/page">
    Click here to open a fullscreen window.
</a>
```

The intent is for this to open a new full-screen window, which the user can then resize/close/move etc. However, under certain conditions the link actually opens what appears to be a kiosk-mode window (no titlebar, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> don't work to exit). To be clear, the page this link is located on is a normal user-started IE 11, Windows 7. We aren't experiencing this issue in Chrome 73, Windows 7, or Edge, Windows 10.

## Additional Details

This launch link is working as intended when deployed to a development environment, whose URL looks something like `https://mydevenv.local/mywebapp/` (intranet), but not when deployed to our production environment `https://apps.ourproductiondomain.com/mywebapp/` (only accessible from our network). It wouldn't surprise me if our organization had site-specific settings for `ourproductiondomain`, but I have no clue where to start looking for a launch-in-kiosk-mode setting.

Using the IE dev tools, I edited the link and location and determined it seems to specifically launch in kiosk mode when the link is from `ourproductiondomain` to `ourproductiondomain`. Editing the link to `https://google.com` launches Google in regular full-screen mode as intended. Editing my markup into Google also opens my new page in regular full-screen mode as intended (with the link fully qualified to `https://apps.ourproductiondomain.com/mywebapp/path/to/my/new/page`).

Interestingly, changing the `fullscreen` to `height=600,width=800` has a title bar and allows the user to control the window, but the buggy version has no address/location bar while the functional version does. Not a detail I care too much about, but it might help troubleshooting efforts.

The application is developed in ASP.NET MVC 5 but I don't think that matters since the rendered markup above is exactly the same in both deployments.

## Question

Does anybody know what might be going on? If that's too broad a question, here's 2 narrow ones that I think might point me in the right direction:

1. How do you purposely and consistently launch a kiosk-mode window in IE 11 with JavaScript?
2. Where can you configure IE 11 with site-specific settings like "Make launched full-screen windows actually kiosk-mode windows"?

Comment: Have you tried a different machine entirely with that version of IE?

Comment: @KevinB Not me personally, but our users have reported this when it was deployed to production for the first time this morning.

Comment: @DPenner1, For testing purpose. Try to lower down the security settings for IE on your production machine to check whether it helps to solve the issue or not. If it work than you can inform your administrators to make necessary changes in settings.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Unfortunately I don't have the privileges for that, though our internal sites are usually already at the lowest security settings.

Comment: Does the suggestion given by tschoffelen to explicitly displaying the menu bar worked for you? Can you please inform us the current status of the issue? According to that we will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT No, the explicit menu bar didn't work. No progress on this, though users have accepted replacing fullscreen with fixed size launch so it's no longer pressing. That said, it's still a curious technical problem, in my opinion.

Comment: You can try to reset IE on 1 machine to check whether it helps to solve the issue or not. You can also try to install the new updates if any available to check whether it helps to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in IE. For security purposes, user scripts aren't supposed to be allowed to open windows in Kiosk Mode.

It does sound like there are some custom system settings in play here, although I wouldn't know where to find that setting.

A possible fix might be to explicitly specify that you want certain parts of the window frame to be visible:

```js
window.open('/path/to/my/new/page', 'windowname', 'fullscreen,toolbar=yes,location=no,statusbar=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')
```

Also, I see that your original script uses `.focus()` directly on the newly created window. I don't think you need it, and feel like that might be what actually causes the bug in IE to be triggered.

Comment: Unfortunately none of your suggestions worked. Good idea with the explicit menubar though, hadn't thought of trying that. I'm definitely starting to concentrate on looking for custom system settings...